# How to stop an object of QGraphicsObjcet without using animation?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

In this program I have a class inheriting of QGraphicsObject. This object (mario) go forward, go back and jump. For this jobs I changed mario's coordinate. But I have a problem. I want it to stop when collide with bricks. While I don't use of QPropertyAnimation how to stop this item.

```
extern mario* _mario=new mario;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent)
{
  size_of_plane_y=600;
  size_of_plane_x=2000;
  view=new QGraphicsView;
  scene=new QGraphicsScene;
  rec=new QGraphicsRectItem;
  setCentralWidget(view);
  view->setScene(scene);
  scene->setSceneRect(0,0,size_of_plane_x,size_of_plane_y);
  scene->addRect(scene->sceneRect());
  x_scene=0;
  y_scene=0;
  int tmpb=8*30+120+10*30+120;
  int tmpb2=10*30+120+8*30+120;
  int firstb=100;
  int firstb2=100+8*30+120;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    _brick=new brick(0,firstb,size_of_plane_y-180);
    scene->addItem(_brick);
    _brick2=new brick2(0,firstb2,size_of_plane_y-180);
    scene->addItem(_brick2);
    firstb+=tmpb;
    firstb2+=tmpb2;
  }
  timer1=new QTimer(this);
  timer1->setInterval(500);
  connect(timer1,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(up()));
};

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *k)
{
  switch (k->key())
  {
    case Qt::Key_J:
    {
      forward();
      break;
    }
    case Qt::Key_Z:
    {
      timer1->start();
      break;
    }
    case Qt::Key_F:
    {
       back();
       break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
}

void MainWindow::forward()
{
   if(ismovepossible(_mario->pos().x()+50,_mario->pos().y())==true)
   {
    _mario->setX(_mario->pos().x()+50);
    scene->setSceneRect(x_scene+40,y_scene,size_of_plane_x,size_of_plane_y);
    x_scene+=40;
   }     
}

void MainWindow::up()
{
  static bool flag=0;
  if(!flag)
  {
    if(ismovepossible(_mario->pos().x(),_mario->pos().y()-90)==true)
    {  
      _mario->setY(_mario->pos().y()-90);
       flag=1;
    }      
  }
  else
  {
    if(ismovepossible(_mario->pos().x(),_mario->pos().y()-90)==true)
   {
    _mario->setY(_mario->pos().y()+90);
    timer1->stop();
    flag=0;
   } 
  }
}

void MainWindow::back()
{

   if(ismovepossible(_mario->pos().x()-50,_mario->pos().y())==true)
   {
    _mario->setX(_mario->pos().x()-50);
    scene->setSceneRect(x_scene-50,y_scene,size_of_plane_x,size_of_plane_y);
    x_scene-=50;
   }
}
////////////////edit
void MainWindow::projectile()//when user press Z and J simultaneity
{
   static bool flag=0;
   if(!flag)
   {
   if(ismovepossible(_mario->pos().x()+50,_mario->pos().y()-90)==true)
   {
    _mario->setY(_mario->pos().y()-90);
    _mario->setX(_mario->pos().x()+50);
    scene->setSceneRect(x_scene+50,y_scene,size_of_plane_x,size_of_plane_y);
     x_scene-=50;
    text->setPos(x_scene+200,10);
     flag=1;
   }
   }
   else
   {
   if(ismovepossible(_mario->pos().x(),_mario->pos().y()+90)==true)
   {
   _mario->setY(_mario->pos().y()+90);
   timer2->stop();
   flag=0;
   }
   }
 }
 /////////////////////add function
 bool MainWindow::ismovepossible(int x, int y)
{
  int dis_b=10*30+120+120;
  int dis_b2=4*30+120+8*30+120;//8*30+120+120;
  int firstb=100;
  int endb=/*firstb*/100+8*30;
  int firstb2=/*endb*/100+8*30+120;
  int endb2=/*firstb2*/100+8*30+120+4*30;
  int firstb3=/*endb2*/100+8*30+120+4*30+2*30;
  int endb3=/*firstb3*/100+8*30+120+4*30+2*30+4*30;
  int dis_b3=120+8*30+120+4*30+2*30;
  if(y>size_of_plane_y-60 && y<=size_of_plane_y)
  {
    return false;
  }
  while(endb<size_of_plane_x)
  {
    if((y>size_of_plane_y-180 && y<size_of_plane_y-180+30)&&(x>firstb && x<endb))
    {
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    firstb+=dis_b;
    endb+=firstb;
    }
  }
  while(endb2<size_of_plane_x)
  {
    if((y>size_of_plane_y-180 && y<size_of_plane_y-180+30)&&(x>firstb2 && x<endb2))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
    firstb2+=dis_b2;
    endb2+=firstb2;
    }
  }
  while(endb3<size_of_plane_x)
  {
    if((y>size_of_plane_y-180 && y<size_of_plane_y-180+30)&&(x>firstb3 && x<endb3))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
    firstb3+=dis_b3;
    endb3+=firstb3;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
class brick : public QGraphicsObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
  explicit brick(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0,int x=100,int y=600-180);
  void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
  QRectF boundingRect()const;
  public slots:
  void collision();

  private:
  int size_of_plane_y;
  int start_x;
  int start_y;
  int size_brick;
};

brick::brick(QGraphicsItem *parent, int x, int y) : QGraphicsObject(parent)
{
  size_of_plane_y=600;
  start_x=x;
  start_y=y;
  size_brick=30;
  connect(_mario,SIGNAL(xChanged()),this,SLOT(collision()));
  connect(_mario,SIGNAL(yChanged()),this,SLOT(collision()));
}

void brick::collision()
{
  if(this->collidesWithItem(_mario))
  {
    qDebug()<<"collision";
    //what write here for stopping super mario? 
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should modify your algorithm. The main problem here is you move mario before checking if there is a brick.

You move mario, you emit the signal xChanged() or yChanged(), check if you're on a brick or not ? Then you have to go back to the previous location ?

Since you know where you put your bricks, you can do something more like this:

```
void MainWindow::forward()
{
    if(moveIsPossible(xDest, yDest))
    {
        _mario->setX(...);
        [...]
}
```

In the moveIsPossible(xDest, yDest), you put the tuple (X,Y) of the future location, it returns true if you have no brick, no wall, no whatever you want, false otherwise.

Seeing your code, I just want to draw your attention on many thing:

- Try to use const variable to put any configuration variable such as board size, brick size, etc ...
- Try to create specific classes for specific function. forward(), back(), etc.. have not to be implemented in the mainwindow class.

Comment: if i do your suggestion is solved my problem? i mean if mario stand up in bricks? my question was how to stand up mario in bricks.if i used of animation i could use stop method.but now what do i do?

Comment: I don't really get your question but I think you are trying to overcome the problem in the wrong way. If I understand, you move mario and then check the bricks. I suggest you to check the obstacles before moving, that way you can have impossible situation such as "mario on bricks".

Comment: i edit my code in my question.but when mario move out of range he hide.where is my wrong?

Comment: What didn't you understand here ? "I suggest you to check the obstacles before moving". To my point of view you have to change your algorithm, you're doing it the wrong way, that's all.